# How to read a private key for use with OpenSAML?

Tags: java, cryptography, opensaml

OK, this is another of those "I have no real idea where to start" questions, so hopefully the answer is simple. However, I don't really know what to search for, and my attempts so far haven't turned up much of use.

I want to read a private key from a (currently on-disk) file. Ultimately the key will reside in a database, but this will be good enough for the moment and that difference should have no real bearing on parsing the key material. I have been able to create a `Credential` instance that holds the public part of the key (confirmed by debugger), but I can't seem to figure out how to read the private part. The key pair was generated as:

```
openssl genrsa 512 > d:\host.key
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -days 365 -key d:\host.key > d:\host.cert
```

(**Yes**, I know that 512 bit RSA keys were broken long ago. However, for trying to get the API to work, I see no reason to exhaust the system entropy supply needlessly.)

The code thus far is:

```
import org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.Credential;
import org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.BasicX509Credential;

private Credential getSigningCredential()
throws java.security.cert.CertificateException, IOException {
    BasicX509Credential credential = new BasicX509Credential();

    credential.setUsageType(UsageType.SIGNING);

    // read public key
    InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("d:\\host.cert");
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
    inStream.close();
    credential.setEntityCertificate(cert);

    // TODO: read private key

    // done.
    return credential;
}
```

But how do I read the file `host.key` into the private key portion of `credential`, so I can use the generated `Credential` instance to sign data?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`BasicX509Credential` is not part from standard Java; I suppose you are talking about `org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.BasicX509Credential` from OpenSAML.

You want a `PrivateKey` which you will set with `credential.setPrivateKey()`. To get a `PrivateKey`, you must first convert the private key into a format that Java can read, namely PKCS#8:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -outform DER < D:\host.key > D:\host.pk8
```

Then, from Java:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("d:\\host.pk8", "r");
byte[] buf = new byte[(int)raf.length()];
raf.readFully(buf);
raf.close();
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec kspec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(buf);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(kspec);
```

and voilà! you have your `PrivateKey`.

By default, `openssl` writes key in its own format (for RSA keys, PKCS#8 happens to be a wrapper around that format), *and* it encodes them in PEM, which Base64 with a header and a footer. Both characteristics are unsupported by plain Java, hence the conversion to PKCS#8. The `-nocrypt` option is because PKCS#8 supports optional password-based encryption of private key.

**Warning:** you really *really* want to use a longer RSA key. 512 bits are weak; a 512-bit RSA key was broken in 1999 with a few hundred computers. In 2011, with 12 years of technological advances, one should assume that a 512-bit RSA key can be broken by almost anybody. Therefore, use 1024-bit RSA keys *at least* (preferably, 2048-bit; the computational overhead when using the key is not that bad, you will still be able to perform hundred of signatures per second).

Comment: Yes, BasicX509Credential is from OpenSAML, sorry about that oversight. I will definitely give this a try. And yes, I know perfectly well that 512-bit RSA keys are not by any means secure, but this particular setup is *strictly* for trying to get things to work at all, so key length is a non-issue.

Comment: Seems to work like a charm, thank you very much! Of course, my signing code appears to be broken, but at least according to the debugger, I get a proper `Credential` from the two files on disk. On with the tour...

Comment: Thank you. I had mysterious troubles with redirecting < and > at Windows, so one may want to replace them with -in and -out switches.

Answer (score 1):

This question is related to SAML and is also relevant for someone who wants to retrieve a private key for signing an XMLObject.  The answer above works great and it also possible to retrieve a private key from a keystore as well:

```
        Properties sigProperties = new Properties();

    sigProperties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider","org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
    sigProperties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type","jks");
    sigProperties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password","keypass");
    sigProperties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias","keyalias");
    sigProperties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file","keystore.jks");

    Crypto issuerCrypto = CryptoFactory.getInstance(sigProperties);

    String issuerKeyName = (String) sigProperties.get("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias");

    //See http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/xref/org/apache/ws/security/saml/ext/AssertionWrapper.html 'signAssertion' method
    // prepare to sign the SAML token
    CryptoType cryptoType = new CryptoType(CryptoType.TYPE.ALIAS);
    cryptoType.setAlias(issuerKeyName);
    X509Certificate[] issuerCerts = issuerCrypto.getX509Certificates(cryptoType);
    if (issuerCerts == null) {
        throw new WSSecurityException(
                "No issuer certs were found to sign the SAML Assertion using issuer name: "
                        + issuerKeyName);
    }

    String password = ADSUnitTestUtils.getPrivateKeyPasswordFromAlias(issuerKeyName);

    PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    try {
        privateKey = issuerCrypto.getPrivateKey(issuerKeyName, password);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new WSSecurityException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }


    BasicX509Credential signingCredential = new BasicX509Credential();
    signingCredential.setEntityCertificate(issuerCerts[0]);
    signingCredential.setPrivateKey(privateKey);

    signature.setSigningCredential(signingCredential);
```

This is more code than the original query requested, but it looks they are trying to get at a BasicX509Credential.

Thanks,
Yogesh